# delete duplicate dictionary object in list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates, attributes

I have the following object and input
I would like to delete duplicate dictionary of object
How I can do it (delete duplicate in `mg`)

p.s. I should not change reading method as it has written or `Meg` or `mg`

```py
class Meg:
    def __init__(self, ss, rr, cd):
        self.ss = ss
        self.rr = rr
        self.cd = cd

if __name__ == '__main__':     
    lines=['842',
            '81 842 81',
            '842 81 81',
            '81 842 81',
            '842 81 81',
            '82 842 82',
            '82 842 82',
            '83 842 83',
            '842 83 83']         
    idd = lines[0].rstrip()
    mg = []
    for line in lines[1:]:
        if not line:
            break
        ss, rr, cd = line.split( ' ')
        mg.append(Meg(ss,rr,cd.rstrip(),),)
```

Comment: I did 
for items in mg:
        temp_list = list()
        if isinstance(items["ss"], list):
            for value in items["ss"]:
                if value not in templist:
                    temp_list.append(value)
            item["ss"] = temp_list
but did not work!

Comment: `for line in lines[1:]` to `for line in set(lines[1:])`

Comment: @DeepakTripathi but I should not change these lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `__hash__` and `__eq__` methods for your class, so that other built-in objects like `sets` and `dicts` can leverage it and consider objects having same `ss`, `rr` and `cd` values as equal objects.

```
class Meg:
    def __init__(self, ss, rr, cd):
        self.ss = ss
        self.rr = rr
        self.cd = cd
    
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.ss, self.rr, self.cd))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self.ss == other.ss and self.rr == other.rr and self.cd == other.cd
    

if __name__ == '__main__':     
    lines=['842',
            '81 842 81',
            '842 81 81',
            '81 842 81',
            '842 81 81',
            '82 842 82',
            '82 842 82',
            '83 842 83',
            '842 83 83']         
    idd = lines[0].rstrip()
    mg = set()
    for line in lines[1:]:
        if not line:
            break
        ss, rr, cd = line.split( ' ')
        mg.add(Meg(ss,rr,cd.rstrip()))
    print(len(mg))
```

this prints `5`, as there are 5 unique objects.

Comment: will this error if you try to do something like compare a Meg type to a non-Meg type?

Comment: @Byron yes of course because `__eq__` takes second parameter an object of type meg. if other object i passed then it should have all those attributes that are in comparison

Comment: `def __eq__(self, other):
        if type(other) == type(self):
            if other.ss == self.ss and other.rr == self.rr and other.cd == self.cd:
                return True
        return False`

Comment: @Byron, good point, added a class type check so that we don't raise an exception. `isinstance(other, self.__class__)`

Comment: thanks, but if we do not have permission to change mg as 'list' of 'dictionaries' to 'set' what we can do?

Comment: @user10296606, are you originally read those from file?

Comment: @OlvinRoght yes

Comment: @user10296606, one more question. Are you using `Meg` class just as a data container to save 3 variables?

Comment: @OlvinRoght yes, I have to work with **Meg**

Comment: @user10296606, depending on how long the list is, you can either convert the `mg` to list again (`list(mg)`) after the for loop to get the list OR if its smaller, you can still use `list` and do the check that `if Meg(meg_obj) not in mg: mg.append(meg_obj)`

Comment: @user10296606, then you can simply use `@dataclass(frozen=True, eq=True)` decorator which automatically implement all hashing logic

Comment: @user10296606, like [this](https://tio.run/##RY@7CsMwDEV3f4XIZJeSpUsJBPoD3boXE8uJIbFdyaUv@u2ucSHRdNDRgxtfaQr@cIyUs6WwgNFJD7NmRga3xEBpawlxWlmW6Tf6/kJ33APeKihRHZxx7ASUYu6AE1Um2ngwfxbi4dIEIaKX1Fg3o9cLtumZGgWawf7POHOFHmxLqM3sPErVUll3Uarql7HoT/kqd7yaluPsklQKbCAoaTzYb84/). Let me know if it fits your requirements so I'll post it as separate answer.

Comment: @user10296606 alternatively you can also remove duplicate lines before and then generate list. [Code](https://tio.run/##VY9BCsMwDATveYXoyS4hl15KoU/oC0oxJpYTgeMYydD29amSQCG6aXZXi8q3jnO@XAsvS5@8CDxwuDWgEzCCc5SpOmcEU2xBpAXmFvpgd886q9Rp8K7yETIrZD7CPijsQ9M0b6ojzAWz4VOkhNlP2NVPPVnwAnFvoODUr7fQh0QZje1YKlMxdtNXtnVjNXFH06D7U/8wZ/mbOymJqrEW4swgQHmPvpblBw).

Comment: @OlvinRoght thanks but if I should not change the codes written in question, how I can do it
I have {mg, Meg} as my **input** and I can only work with them without changing the reading section from file or definition of **object** **Meg** or **mg**

Comment: @Jay you can see  the length of it is not too long but one point is if we are not able to change the codes written in question, how we can solve it

Comment: @user10296606, which part are you allowed to change, you can't change the class definition? or you can't change the line `mg.append(Meg(ss,rr,cd.rstrip(),),)`. Can you write a code after that line?

Comment: @Jay I can only add code to what has written in question

Comment: You can add the `__hash__` and `__eq__` methods to your code in question or  `@dataclass(frozen=True, eq=True)` as suggested by @OlivinRought and keep rest of the code same, and add `mg = list(set(mg))` after for loop.

Comment: @jay thanks, if I want to count number of a "ss" equal to an specific amount (for instance:  ss=81) what I should do?

Comment: @user10296606, you can do something like `sum([1 for item in mg if item.ss==81])`